# Can we ask questions related to model recommendations?

Tags: discussion

Can we ask questions about deep learning model recommendations/suggestions like which model to choose or for any reference links??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but do not use the words *recommendation* or *suggestion* in your questions. Avoid words that can lead to opinions and try to ask questions that can be answered objectively and that are as much specific as possible, i.e. ask for facts or evidence.

For example, the question "Which model *should* I use for object detection?" is not very specific, and can lead to opinions (because you're using "should"). There are many models for object detection. You should at least describe which objects you want to detect (and, in general, your dataset), and why you're asking for a reference model to use: haven't you found one already by searching the web? If yes, share it with us, and explain why you think it's not "good enough". A better way of rephrasing that question would be

> Which models are more likely to perform well on this specific problem X with this data Y? I have found models Z and W, but, given that I am not very familiar with them, I don't know which one is more appropriate for my scenario.

or something like that.

You can also ask for references (paper, books, articles), but, again, try to be specific and explain your problem well and why are you looking for a reference.